# Why don't I hear sound?

Tags: python, game-engine, audio

I made this code to control the sound of my car in a game very specifically:

```
    import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
sound = cont.actuators['Sound']
ray = cont.sensors['Radar'].positive
velocity = own.localLinearVelocity
speedY = velocity.Y

#control volume and pitch
if ray:
    sound.volume = (.2 * (math.sqrt(speedY)) ^ .6) + .2
    sound.pitch = (.00128 * (speedY)) -.125

    cont.activate(sound)
```

I used the bricks without the code and an and controller and it worked fine, so the sensor does activate correctly. So there's something wrong with the code. I'm not hearing anything so what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the [console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/introduction.html) you will see an error being reported

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'float'

In python `^` is a [bitwise XOR operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) while [`**`, `pow()` or `math.pow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.pow) is used for power.